# Returning a list of results in excel from a wider dataset

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a data set and used google sheets and the filter function to return a set of outputs based on a criteria
That filter function doesn't exist on my version of excel of PC
What is an alternative I can use to get the same output

Data Set:

[image]

Formula used in sheets:

```
=FILTER(A2:A16,K2:K16="Operations")
```

Output would be a list of employee names who were in the department operations

Any help on replicating this on excel would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to use `AGGREGATE()` and few other formulas to obtain filtered result for older versions.

Comment: FYI - I did a check and the formula that provided works in Google sheets and Excel. I am using Excel - Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise. I realize that you might not have this version. Make sure the location that you place the formula has enough area to expand.       `=FILTER(A2:A16,K2:K16="Operations")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **[Harun24hr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr)** Sir, has mentioned you need to use `AGGREGATE()` Function since your **Excel Desktop version**, don't have access to `FILTER()` Function that means you are not using either **Excel 2021** or **O365**, hence refer the formula as shown in below,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=IF(ROWS($F$2:F2)<=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$16,"Operations"),
INDEX($A$2:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2)+1)
/($D$2:$D$16="Operations"),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The reason I have used a `COUNTIF()` Function is that, it gives the counts of number employees in `Operations` Department and gives the output for those accordingly, thus excluding the use of `IFERROR()` Function & makes more **robust** formula!

---

However, these are the few alternatives, which you may try as well,

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($A$2:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2)+1)
/($D$2:$D$16="Operations"),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Or,

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($A$2:$A$16,SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$16="Operations",
ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW(A1))),"")
```

---

**Note:** Using `SMALL()` Function you may need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` based on your Excel Version, however using `AGGREGATE()` usually it doesn't require! Also, since i have used the `Department` in `Column D` you may need to adjust the formula in your workbook with `Column K`. Therefore the formula will be

```
=IF(ROWS($A$2:A2)<=COUNTIF($K$2:$K$16,"Operations"),
INDEX($A$2:$A$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2)+1)
/($K$2:$K$16="Operations"),ROW(A1))),"")
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For others looking at these post there is a easier solution if you have access to the current version of excel. Sorry to hear Murtaza that you don't have access to the current version of Excel.

For both Google sheets and Excel the formula that provided works. I am using Excel - **Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise**.
Make sure the location that you place the formula has enough area to expand.

```
=FILTER(A2:A16,K2:K16="Operations")
```